# trying to learn functions .what is the error in this code..(mysql)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn functions. What is the error in this code?

```
CREATE FUNCTION funname2() RETURNS  varchar(1000)
BEGIN
declare str varchar(500);
set str=update users set last_login_date= now() where  mobile_login= "9886766378" ;

RETURN str;
END
```

Comment: `str` it used to store an single value or a column value. the use of `set str=update users set last_login_date= now() where mobile_login= "9886766378" ;` is not correct here.

Comment: ok sir..thank you for your response

Comment: Can you please also post what error did you get as output?

Comment: ErrorMessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update
users set last_login_date=now() where mobile_login= '9886766378';
    RE' at line 4

Comment: sir this is the error showing when i'm using that code